# How to get the value inside the input of type text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var data = document.getElementById('myFieldId');
console.log(data.value);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myFieldId"/>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect when I write any text in the input, it would print the corresponding text. But I don't get anything in the console. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if the sample code snippet above matches your exact code scenario, but the trick here is that you're trying to read the value before the field renders (thus it is undefined)... if you run the JavaScript after the field exists (and you have a value in the field e.g. `<input type="text" id="myFieldId" value="Initial Value"/>` ) you will see the value print out in the console.

Comment: @scunliffe The value of a text input is never undefined, it might be the empty string, but not undefined.

Comment: @Teemu that isn't quite correct. It will be an empty string if no value is set yet, however the variable `data` in this case, will be undefined, **if** the `document.getElementById('myFieldId');` is called *before* the field is rendered in the DOM.

Comment: In that case the value of `data` would be `null`, and `data.value` would trigger an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an **event listener** that executes as soon as someone inputs text.

There is no such thing as *binding a variable to a text input*; this needs to be implemented by yourself.

See this example:

```js
const data = document.getElementById('myFieldId');

data.addEventListener(
  'input', // first argument is the name of the event you want to react to
  // second argument is the function that should execute when the event occurs
  function(inputEvent) {
    console.log(data.value);
  }
);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myFieldId"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You code start at load page so is empty, i add an `onchange` event so when you finish to write `console.log` will output the value.

```js
var data = document.getElementById('myFieldId');
data.onchange = function()
{
  console.log(this.value);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="myFieldId"/>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The original code has been changed to be less offensive. I don't know why this answer has been downvoted, but it's just possible that matching the edited id name would be sensible

Comment: Do not use offensive words anywhere in your posts. This includes any names your pick for variables, vlass names, function names etc. The next edit/rollback to the offensive post state earns you a flag.